# Can you make a 'named' format in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to make a named format applied to cells and then change that format and it cascade to all cells using that format?  That way I can format certain numerical values and if the need changes I can just change the named format.

Comment: I ended up using 'find/replace' format to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Cell Styles](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-create-or-remove-a-cell-style-HP001216732.aspx#BMmodifystyle).

**To create one:**

1. Go to Home > Cell Styles > New Cell Style
2. Type a name for your custom style.
3. Check what you want to include in your custom style.

   [image]
4. Click **Format**, and start customizing.

**To apply:**

1. Highlight the cells you want to apply the style to.
2. Go to Home > Cell Styles
3. Pick your style from the list

**To modify your style/format:**

1. Go to Home > Cell Styles
2. Right-click the button for your style
3. Click Modify
4. Start customizing

Any changes you make to the style will automatically reflect on cells to which it's been applied.